# Run time error while reversing a link list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am creating a simple linklist of integers and then reversing it. While reversing, last integer in original list is not getting printed. Instead a garbage value is printed. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct list
{
    int node;
    struct list *next; 
};

void insert(struct list **, int);
void print(struct list *);

int main()
{
    struct list *mylist= NULL, *tmp = NULL;

    insert(&mylist, 10);

    tmp = mylist;
    insert(&mylist, 20);
    insert(&mylist, 30);
    insert(&mylist, 40);
    insert(&mylist, 50);
    insert(&mylist, 60);
    insert(&mylist, 70);
    mylist=tmp;
    reverse(&mylist);
    printf("hello  ");
    print(mylist);

    return 0;
}

void reverse(struct list **temp)
{
    struct list **pre, **aft, **head;
    *pre = NULL;
    *head = *temp;
    if(*head == NULL )
        {
        return;
        }
    else
    {
        while((*head)!= NULL)
        {

        *aft =(*head)->next;

        (*head)->next = *pre;
        *pre = *head;
        *head = (*aft);
         printf("%d\t",(*pre)->node);
        }

    *temp = *pre;         
    }           
    }

void print(struct list *head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
            while(head!=NULL)
            {
             printf("%d\t",head->node);
             head=head->next;       
        }
    }
}


void insert(struct list **head, int value)
{   
    struct list *new_node;
    new_node = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

//node Creation
    new_node->node=value;
    new_node->next=NULL;

//Adding Node to list
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        *head=new_node;  

    }
    else
    {
        while((*head)->next!=NULL)
        {   
            *head=(*head)->next;

        }
        (*head)->next=new_node;

    }

}
```

Output:
10 20 30 40 50 60 6532425 hello  6532425 60 50 40 30 20 10

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your dereferencing and writing to indeterminate locations by doing this:

```
struct list **pre, **aft, **head;
*pre = NULL;    // <=== HERE
*head = *temp;  // <=== HERE
```

Neither of those pointers are initialized to anything, and are therefore indeterminate. dereferencing them for reading, writing, or even *evaluating* the pointer value itself is **undefined behavior**.

Fixing that is easy enough, since this function should not need any pointer-to-pointer variables *except* the passed in head pointer (which it must have by-address to reset the new list head once it is reversed).

```
void reverse(struct list **head)
{
    struct list *back = NULL, *cur = *head, *fwd = NULL;
    while (cur && cur->next)
    {
        fwd = cur->next;
        cur->next = back;
        back = cur;
        cur = fwd;
    }

    if (cur)
        cur->next = back;

    *head = cur;
}
```

That said, evidence suggests your work with pointers-to-pointers needs some more practice. There are additional errors, noted below

---

**Memory leak in `insert()`**

In your `insert()` function:

```
while((*head)->next!=NULL)
{
    *head=(*head)->next;

}
(*head)->next=new_node;
```

This code blindly overwrites the passed-in head pointer by-address, and in the process leaks any previously allocated nodes except the the last-one-added. If you're going to receive a double pointer and use it for walking the list to find the location of the new insertion, do so correctly. The pointer-game being played with `tmp` in `main()` should not be necessary, and with the following implementation, it isn't:

```
void insert(struct list **head, int value)
{
    // find the address of the last `next` pointer in
    // the list. note: it may be the head pointer itself
    while (*head)
        head = &(*head)->next; 

    *head = malloc(sizeof(**head));
    (*head)->node = value;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
}
```

---

**Simplify `print()`**

A minor inconvenience in your `print()` code is also present. There is no need for the initial check for the passed in pointer as NULL. Just use the break-condition of the while loop:

```
void print(struct list *head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        printf("%d ",head->node);
        head=head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

**Putting It All Together**

Using the above implementations, and the following `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    struct list *mylist = NULL;

    insert(&mylist, 10);
    insert(&mylist, 20);
    insert(&mylist, 30);
    insert(&mylist, 40);
    insert(&mylist, 50);
    insert(&mylist, 60);
    insert(&mylist, 70);

    print(mylist);
    reverse(&mylist);
    print(mylist);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 
70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this declaration:

```
struct list **pre, **aft, **head;
```

So, they are pointers to a pointer to a list, and then, you do things like this:

```
*pre = NULL;
```

The problem is that `pre` has not been initialized, so it holds garbage at this point. You are basically setting a random address in memory to NULL.
You have two options: allocate space for them (with malloc and free afterwards), or change them to be like this:

```
struct list *pre, *aft, *head;
```

That way, they can be assigned safely. Your function would be modified like this:

```
void reverse(struct list **temp) {
    struct list *pre, *aft, *head;
    pre = NULL;
    head = *temp;
    if(head == NULL ) {
        return;
    } else {
        while(head!= NULL) {
            aft =head->next;
            head->next = pre;
            pre = head;
            head = aft;
            printf("%d\t",pre->node);
        }
        *temp = pre;
    }
}
```

Doing that, I get the following output:

```
10      20      30      40      50      60      70      hello  70       60
50      40      30      20      10
```

EDIT:

I've also noticed that you are changing the value of `head` inside the functions `insert` and `print`. I recommend using a temporal variable instead to iterate the list. That also frees you from that trick you were using in `main` with `tmp`.

Anyway, the complete code modified can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/qNZgGi). If yours is still giving you trouble, post an update or Ideone link with the modified code that still fails.

Comment: Interestingly, you could do away with the `if` clause altogether, just keeping the body of the else clause as the whole function.  When `head == NULL`, the loop will be executed zero times, and the `*temp = pre;` will assign NULL, and the condition already showed that `head`, aka `*temp`, was NULL.  It simplifies the code at the possible cost of a redundant assignment (which will be about as costly as the test required to avoid making it).

Comment: After allocating space to them I am getting 0 instead of 70